# Tic Tac Toe no winner

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner in android development and I'm trying to build a tic tac toe game with the help of an instructor-led course.

I have already added two winning conditions for two players but I want to add a condition for no winner or draw state.

How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // 0 : yellow, 1 : red, empty : 2

    int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,};

    int[][] winningPositions = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};

    int activePlayer = 0;

    boolean gameActive = true;

    public void dropIn(View view) {
        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

        if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameActive) {

            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

            counter.setTranslationY(-1500);
            if (activePlayer == 0) {

                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                activePlayer = 1;

            } else {

                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            counter.animate().translationYBy(1500).setDuration(400);
            for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

                    String winner = "";

                    gameActive = false;
                    if (activePlayer == 1) {
                        winner = "Yellow";
                    } else {
                        winner = "Red";
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(this, winner + " have won!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
                    TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);

                    winnerTextView.setText(winner + " has won!");

                    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void playAgain(View view){
        Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
        TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        for(int i=0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
            ImageView counter = (ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
            counter.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++){
            gameState[i] = 2;
        }

        activePlayer = 0;

        gameActive = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: when nobody winds then it is a draw, right?

Comment: yes no winner is draw.

Comment: so when nobody wins you can say it is a draw

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple - you will have to know when every field is taken (somebody put a 'X' or 'O' on it)
So, when every field is taken and there is no winning position fulfilled - then it's a draw.

**From a program's point of view:**

1) When player1 or player2 make a move - calculate free fields that are left

2) When free fields == 0 call a draw() function or something like that

Answer (score 0):

No condition for no winner because the turn is yours and the rules are the same.

You can cheat by using [Minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) to predict the next turn for the player. No player will win if they trust in the algorithm, just draw.

With case player vs computer, Minimax algorithm is also a good choice. You can't beat computer.

Besides, [alpha beta algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) is improved.

You can refers tictactoe window application by Java [Here](https://github.com/quannv132/tictactoe_ai)